# Angular 2 https call not able to trigger

Tags: angular, alfresco, postman

I am calling https call to Alfresco using postman. Its works fine with Authorization, headers, body and in setting I am changing `SSL certificate verification` as `off`. By default that is `on`.

I am calling angular 2 http request as follows:

```
  form: FormData = new FormData();

  method() {
    this.form.append("filename", this.tempFileName);
    this.form.append('filedata', this.tempFileData);
    this.form.append('overwrite', 'true');

    var headersData = new Headers();
    headersData.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(environment.alfrescoCredentials));

    this.http.post(alfrescoUrl, this.form, { headers: headersData })
    .map((res: Response) => {}).subscribe();
 }
```

How to send `SSL certificate verification` as `off` to Alfresco? I am getting following console error on calling https request

`ERROR Response with status: 0  for URL: null`

Comment: The SSL issues with invalid certificates can be bypassed because this is a warning from your browser, you can navigate to `alfrescoUrl`'s value and tell your browser not to worry about the invalid certificate. Then your requests should work perfectly.

Comment: How to change that in browser? I must do that in code level.

Comment: You can't, the only options are: Change the certificate for a valid one, Accept the invalid certificate on browser, disable ssl certificate validation in your browser settings. The reason why you can't turn off the ssl check warning in code is simple: if you could, SSL check would be useless because everyone could simply disable the check.